How to get rid of cells which are referenced without producing #REF! error in other cell's formula?
I tried the following but it's not working. Other sheets that are referencing the cells in the active sheet get #REF! in their formulas. How to prevent Excel from checking references temporarily while the deletion is happening?
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EvaluateToError = False
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EmptyCellReferences = False

ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EvaluateToError = True
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EmptyCellReferences = True


Instead of deleting clear the cells. And give them new values before you turn on auto-recalculate.
Sub CellClear()
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
   ' recreate cell values
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

